# Performance gain of splitting a big class into smaller ones in python

Tags: python, performance, class

Let's say we have a class which had a lot of methods. Is it beneficial to split the class into several smaller classes?

What I think is that a class with lots of methods might have a longer method lookup time than the smaller classes'. And by splitting the class into smaller ones, we might get the speed boost when we call a method? (Especially in a loop.)

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python :)

Comment: @CyrilJouve "Simple is better than complex", smaller classes are simpler, so you're saying they should do it?

Comment: Note: If you'll ever reach a point where you actually need to optimize method lookup times, then Python was a wrong choice to begin with...

Comment: You can easily test this. The methods don't actually have to do anything, just create a bunch of them, call them, then create the same number of methods but one per class. You'll barely see any difference in performance. If anything, it could be slightly slower if you instantiate hundreds of classes just to call a single method.

Comment: "Significant" performance gains can come from looking at the algorithm, not the syntax.